# Digitizable square

Tags: box

How do I insert a digitable square as in the image below? And how do I have these customized letters like R, P, S (P and S are used in Linear Algebra).

[image: Box]

Comment: I am not sure what "digitizable"/"digitable"  means in this context. Could you explain that, please? Apart from that, `\mathfrak` can be used for the letter "R": `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
$\mathfrak{R}$
\end{document}`

Comment: How do I insert this box, or lines around the text as in Theorem?

Comment: `\newtcbtheorem` from the `tolorbox` might come in handy in order to get referenceable, auto-numbered and boxed theorems. Something like `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbtheorem{mytheorem}{Theorem}{colback=white,colframe=black,sharp corners,fontupper=\itshape, fonttitle=\upshape\bfseries\color{black},theorem style=plain,}{th}
\begin{document}
\begin{mytheorem}{}{label}
  text...
\end{mytheorem}
See \ref{th:label} 
\end{document}` should serve as a starting point.